# Remove extra spacing on tab bar - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

As you can see in the image below, there is a little bit of extra grey space above my tab bar that appears on my simulator as well.

[image]

I have the following code that presents a view over the custom tab bar view:

```
-(void)presentThisView :(UINavigationController*)naVController{
    if(prevController != nil){
        [prevController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    prevController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    prevController = naVController;
    CGRect frame = prevController.view.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height;
    prevController.view.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:prevController.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tabView];
}
```

Is there a way to remove that grey space? I'm thinking the view isn't long enough, but I don't know how to extend it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: look at view debugger, and see what's happening there. Are the icons too small or the image is small, you will find out if by looking at view debugger.